# what is ln -sfv in UNIX?

Tags: macos, unix

I am installing redis using brew command. I am following the link at  https://medium.com/@petehouston/install-and-config-redis-on-mac-os-x-via-homebrew-eb8df9a4f298#.or6pxi4ij . Here the code

```
   $ ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/redis/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

is not understandable to me. I google and found what ln command is used for, and that -s and -f are used to forcibly create a soft link. But what is -sfv used for ? I have tried to google it but I did not find a solution yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you figured out, `-s` is for soft link, `-f` is to force it. `-v` ist just to be verbose. From the man page:

```
-v    Cause ln to be verbose, showing files as they are processed.
```

A lot of unix commands support combining short options. So, instead of writing

```
ln -s -f -v something
```

one can just write

```
ln -sfv something
```